# Error opening Visual Studio Code from Cypress on Mac: 'The editor process exited with an error: spawn EACCES'

Tags: macos, terminal, permissions, visual-studio, cypress

I am trying to open ***Visual Studio Code*** from Cypress on my Mac by clicking on a file in the Cypress Test Runner, but I am encountering the following error message in VSC:

> "Could not open myfirstspec.cy.js in the editor. The editor process exited with an error: spawn EACCES."

This is my first time using Cypress, and I have already tried changing the file permissions, running Visual Studio Code as an administrator using the sudo command in Terminal, and reinstalling both Cypress and Visual Studio Code, but the error persists.

---

**Terminal Input**

File Permission: `chmod +x myfirstspec.cy.js`

Visual Studio Code: `sudo /Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron`

---

What could be causing this error, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Cross-posting is discouraged : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76118102/error-opening-visual-studio-code-from-cypress-on-mac-the-editor-process-exited

Comment: @harrymc Sorry, I didn't know that, but thank you for the information. I only resorted to cross-posting because I wasn't getting any responses. I won't do it again. Any suggestions about my problem?

Comment: You should find what `myfirstspec.cy.js` is and why it's needed and especially why it's missing.

Comment: @harrymc `myfirstspec.cy.js` is a test file in Cypress that contains test cases for my application. It's required to run Cypress tests, and I've already checked the file path to ensure it exists. I suspect that the issue is related to permissions.

Comment: Should be easy enough to check the permissions, but you should also verify that the right path is used.